# Ошибка при запуске Activity: Error Inflating class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Добавил к `Activity` `TextInputLayout` прямиком с сайта material, вот код:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:hint="Урок"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:inputType="none"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Стиль добавил:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Зависимости есть:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Выскакивает ошибка:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.VitalySorokin.kotlindiary/com.example.kotlindiary.loginregister.RegisterActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #102 in com.VitalySorokin.kotlindiary:layout/activity_register: Binary XML file line #102 in com.VitalySorokin.kotlindiary:layout/activity_register: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #102 in com.VitalySorokin.kotlindiary:layout/activity_register: Binary XML file line #102 in com.VitalySorokin.kotlindiary:layout/activity_register: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #102 in com.VitalySorokin.kotlindiary:layout/activity_register: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.kotlindiary.loginregister.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.kt:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:248)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:222)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:150)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:120)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:424)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:396)
```

Абсолютно такой же код и зависимости я опробовал в новом проекте, там все работает, но в главном не получается. Что делать?

Comment: у вас ничего красным не подчеркнуто в xml? приложите пожалуйста код активности с данным текстовым полем, еще довольно высокая вероятность того что в последней версии библиотеки будут какие-то косяки

Comment: попробуйте в родительском макете подключить тему `android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"`

Comment: @Andrew нет, не подчеркнут. насчет темы сейчас попробую

Comment: @Andrew О БОЖЕ, сработало! Спасибо! Это удивительно, но оно работает. В тестовом проекте в родительском макете не был подключен параметр theme, но там так же работало, странно. В общем благодарю)